# Why can I "move" a static &str into multiple threads in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, rust

I'd like to better understand the semantics behind the following Rust code:

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let immutable = "I am not mutable";
    let mut mutable = "I am mutable";

    let handle1 = thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("Thread 1 says: {}", immutable);
    });

    let handle2 = thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("Thread 2 says: {}", immutable);
    });

    let handle3 = thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("Thread 3 says: {}", mutable);
        mutable = "go away";
    });

    let handle4 = thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("Thread 4 says: {}", mutable);
    });

    handle1.join().unwrap();
    handle2.join().unwrap();
}
```

I do not understand why this code compiles. I have shared the variable `mutable` between multiple threads and even mutated it. What exactly is going on behind-the-scenes with the memory here? Are we making multiple pointers to the same string in static memory? Are we placing two different static strings in memory? The fact that I can have two threads reading from the same immutable item doesn't surprise me, but having two threads reading from a mutable variable does.

Note that even if thread 3 runs before 4, 4 does not reflect the updated string that thread 3 sets in its `println!` statement. Finally, since I didn't pass using `&immutable`, does this mean that the *value* is being "moved" into each thread rather than the actual memory address?

Comment: What you forget is that your type is `&static str`, here the same sniped with a simple struct, https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2fb38b955b26dea7291fbacd270a8e7a&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015.

Comment: @Stargateur I get your point but I don't understand how this relates to my original question in the context of &static str. I did know that &static str I just don't understand why that is able to be passed as mutable and used in multiple threads.

Comment: Essentially, you're asking why you can use `let mut other = mutable;`. Keep in mind that `mutable: &str`, not `mutable: &mut str`. You never change the slice itself. Or, speaking in C terms, you have a `char const * mutable` and a `char const * const immutable` and therefore are not able to change the contents anyway. And similar to C, `mutable = "go away"` only changes the slice, not its contents (C lingua: you change the pointer, not the pointed value), with the same semantics as `let mutable_local = mutable` beforehand, so the outer `mutable` stays intact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have shared the same variable mutable between multiple threads and even mutated it.

No, you have copied a reference to the same static string into multiple threads.  The reference points to a constant static string which can't be mutated. Read-only references are `Copy`, so you can move them into multiple closures.

> What exactly is going on behind-the-scenes with the memory here?

A string slice is essentially a pointer to the beginning of a string in memory together with a length.  Your variables `mutable` and `immutable` only contain these two pieces of information, and only these pieces are mutable for `mutable`.  The actual strings the variables point to are immutable.  When "moving" the variables into the closures, they are actually copied, since `&str` is `Copy`.  The only information that is copied is the pointer and the length, not the actual string data.  You end up with multiple pointers to the same read-only memory, which doesn't allow for any data races and conforms to Rust's memory safety rules.

> Also, note that even if thread 3 runs before 4, 4 does not reflect the updated string that thread 3 sets in its println! statement.

You only modify the copy of the pointer and the length.  In thread 3, `mutable` becomes a separate variable local to the closure, and you only modify that.

> Finally, since I didn't pass using `&immutable`, does this mean that the value is being "moved" into each thread rather than the actual memory address?

The variable `immutable` has the type `&'static str`, so it is already a reference; `&immutable` would be a reference to a reference.